# Command not found after npm link

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a small node.js app "doto" that I want to `npm link`, so that I can just call `doto` anywhere. As of my understanding all I need to do is:

```
mkdir doto
cd doto
npm init #call the project doto and entry point doto.js
touch doto.js #fill with some code
npm link
```

`node doto.js` works just fine, but when I link the package and try to call `doto`, the command is not found. The linking went fine, I had to use sudo (yes I know I should setup node a way that I do not need sudo, but for now I just want to get my feet wet)

Whenever I install a package globally, I can call it just fine.

I am running mac os 10.10.

doto.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var path = require('path');
var pkg = require( path.join(__dirname, 'package.json') );

var program = require('commander');

program
    .version(pkg.version)
    .option('-p, --port <port>', 'Port on which to listen to (defaults to 3000)', parseInt)
    .parse(process.argv);

console.log(program.port);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "doto",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "doto.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "~2.7.1"
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your `package.json` is missing the bin section, [according to the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) it should become something like:

```
{
  "name": "doto",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "doto.js",
  // specify a bin attribute so you could call your module
  "bin": {
    "doto": "./doto.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "~2.7.1"
  }
}
```

So after you've run `sudo npm link` you can run `doto` from anywhere, if you want to change the name of the executable just change the key under "bin" to whatever you prefer.

Comment: See, sometimes I feel really stupid :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad that helped ;D Don't forget to upvote please.

Comment: My package.json is not missing the "bin" section but I cannot use the command in my terminal after doing "npm link ."

Answer (score 0):

I tried `npm link` and it still was not working from my test package.

My `package.json` in the linked package had `"directories": { "bin": "./bin" }` instead of `"bin": { "etc": "./etc.js" }`.

Once I changed it back to `"bin": {...}` it started to work in the test package.

So, although this `directories: { bin: ... }` setting is [documented](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#directoriesbin) it doesn't seem to work correctly with `npm link`.